Duplicate Notification is coming for flutter local notification when the app is in background mode. How to solve?
I have a dashboard screen where in the initState I am initializing the Firebase notification and local notification. When the app is foregrounded it's getting the local notification and getting the notification correctly. But when the app is backgrounded then it's getting two notifications one from the firebaseMessaging and another from the local notification which is kind of duplicate and false. I want to get rid of it and want only the Firebase messaging to work when the app is backgrounded.
Community suggests this might be my solve:
Notification show twice on flutter. But the available solution on that are not for me. If i dont use the navigation from the payload that solves might work but if i dont use message.notification the how can I navigate from notifications? So as per my understanding both are different questions. And more over the notification from the local notification, the payload is coming as empty. But in the second notification the payload is coming with data.
My code snippets:
initState
@override
 void initState() {
    super.initState();

    currentTab = widget.tab;
    initFirebaseMessaging();
    _selectTab(currentTab);
  }

Firebase messaging
 initFirebaseMessaging() async {
    await firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );
    final fcm = await firebaseMessaging.getToken();
    logger.w("Driver Token: $fcm");
    initPushNotification();
    initLocalNotifications();
  }

Push notifications
Future initPushNotification() async {
    ///if app is opened from terminated state : onTap actions performed
    firebaseMessaging.getInitialMessage().then(
      (RemoteMessage? message) {
        if (initialRemoteMessage != null) {
          RemoteNotification? notification = initialRemoteMessage!.notification;
          logger.w(
              "Driver title:${notification?.title} Driver data: ${notification?.body}");
          logger.w("Driver Data:${message?.data}");
          moveScreenFromNotification(initialRemoteMessage!.data);
          flutterToast(initialRemoteMessage!.messageType ?? '');
        } else if (message != null) {
          RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
          logger.w("RemoteNotification");
          logger.w("title:${notification?.title} data: ${notification?.body}");
          logger.w("Data:${message.data}");
          moveScreenFromNotification(message.data);
          flutterToast(message.messageType ?? '');
          initialRemoteMessage = message;
        }
      },
    );

    //*If app is in background state : actions performed
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {
      moveScreenFromNotification(message.data);
    });
    //*If app is in background state
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(handleBackGroundMessage);

    //* If the app is in foreground state:(Local notifications)
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
      final notification = message.notification;
      if (notification == null) return;
      moveScreenFromNotification(message.data);
      localNotification.show(
          notification.hashCode,
          notification.title,
          notification.body,
          NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                  androidChannel.id, androidChannel.name)),
          payload: jsonEncode(message.toMap()));
    });
  }

Local notifications
    Future initLocalNotifications() async {
    const ios = IOSInitializationSettings();
    const android = AndroidInitializationSettings("@drawable/logo");
    const setting = InitializationSettings(android: android, iOS: ios);
    await localNotification.initialize(setting,
        onSelectNotification: (payload) {
      if (payload?.contains(".pdf") ?? false) {
        logger.w("PDF Executing");
        OpenFile.open(payload);
      } else {
        logger.w("Driver Message is Executing");
        logger.w("Payload: $payload");
        final message = RemoteMessage.fromMap(jsonDecode(payload ?? ""));
        logger.w("DATA from local: ${message.data}");
        handleBackGroundMessage(message);
        moveScreenFromNotification(message.data);
      }
    });
    final platform = localNotification.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
        AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>();
    await platform?.createNotificationChannel(androidChannel);
  }

handle background message
  Future<void> handleBackGroundMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
  RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
  NotificationService notificationService = NotificationService(channelId: "D");
  await notificationService.showNotification(message: message);
  flutterToast(notification?.body ?? '');
  }

These are all the associated snippets. Is there any way to get one notification  while the app is in the background and not use the local notification function?
my manifest.xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.xxxxxxxx">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" 
     android:maxSdkVersion="32"/> 


    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:label="BitesVilla">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/logo" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.wallet.api.enabled"
            android:value="true" />    
        
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="${GMP_KEY}" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
                android:resource="@style/NormalTheme" />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
          


            <!-- Deep linking -->
            <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                 <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="bitesvilla.page.link" android:pathPrefix="/"/>
                <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="bitesvilla.page.link" android:pathPrefix="/"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <meta-data         
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"                 
            android:value="high_importance_channel" />
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"

            android:value="2" />

        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver"/>
        <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>


    <!-- Provide required visibility configuration for API level 30 and above -->
    <queries>
        <!-- If your app checks for SMS support -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
        </intent>
        <!-- If your app checks for call support -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>

I have tried logging to understand what is going on. But it seems like the way of implementation is causing this. I cannot think of anything better for now as I am kind of new to the local notifications.

This question is similar to: Notification show twice on flutter. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Well that situation might look like similer but the issue is I need to work with the payload data like to send it to a required screen. And most importantly the local notification code snippet what you are seeing is getting empty payload only.

Remove FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(handleBackGroundMessage);
and it will only work from Firebase notification when the app is in the background

You should only use firebase to handle notifications, you don't need to use a local notification package.

@Sayid FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(handleBackgroundMessage); by removing this also not works as the notification is getting twice and for the first notification it comes to local notification where the payload is empty.

In your code, you're also using the localNotification package to show a notification when the app is in the background, which is causing the duplicate notification.

@MansoorMalik I need the local notification for the foreground . Tell me the way to solve it! please

await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
alert: true,
badge: true,
sound: true,
);
add this code to your initialization method, and firebase notification will work when the application is in the foreground.

Try this, I hope it works.
I've added a check to only show the local notification when the app is in the foreground. When the app is in the background, FCM will handle the notification and display it to the user.
Future initPushNotification() async {
  ///If app is opened from terminated state : onTap actions performed
  firebaseMessaging.getInitialMessage().then(
    (RemoteMessage? message) {
      if (initialRemoteMessage!= null) {
        RemoteNotification? notification = initialRemoteMessage!.notification;
        logger.w(
            "Driver title:${notification?.title} Driver data: ${notification?.body}");
        logger.w("Driver Data:${message?.data}");
        moveScreenFromNotification(initialRemoteMessage!.data);
        flutterToast(initialRemoteMessage!.messageType?? '');
      } else if (message!= null) {
        RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
        logger.w("RemoteNotification");
        logger.w("title:${notification?.title} data: ${notification?.body}");
        logger.w("Data:${message.data}");
        moveScreenFromNotification(message.data);
        flutterToast(message.messageType?? '');
        initialRemoteMessage = message;
      }
    },
  );

  //*If app is in background state : actions performed
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {
    moveScreenFromNotification(message.data);
  });

  //*If app is in foreground state:(Local notifications)
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
    if (message.notification!= null) {
      // Show local notification only when app is in foreground
      localNotification.show(
          message.notification.hashCode,
          message.notification.title,
          message.notification.body,
          NotificationDetails(
              android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
                  androidChannel.id, androidChannel.name)),
          payload: jsonEncode(message.toMap()));
    }
  });
}


If you can check my code I already have handled the null notification condition.
